# Avoid truncation of float in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Min Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
foo = (0.000410692+0.00352372j) 
np.array([foo], dtype=np.complex_) #gives array([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
np.array([foo]) # same  ([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
np.array([complex(foo)]) # same  ([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
np.array([foo], dtype=np.complex64) # same ([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
np.array([foo], dtype=np.complex128) # same  ([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
np.array([complex(foo)], dtype=np.complex128) # same  ([0.00041069+0.00352372j])
```

How do I get `array([0.000410692+0.00352372j])`, with the original complex values without loss in precision. ?

Comment: Those are the visible numbers. You could format it to print more numbers. eg `f'{foo:.20f}'`

Comment: @Onyambu Oh cool, thanks. create the post as an answer & I'll mark it as answered.